# DatePicker picking same values for all in Angular

Tags: angular

I am working on an application in which i am using 3rd party datePicker. So in this application i have used two datepicker **from date** and **to date**. The problem is when I set date value in **from date**, the same value gets set in **to date** also which is incorrect.

**Below are the sample code for understanding**

**app.component.html**

```
      <input [owlDateTime]="dt1" [(ngModel)]="dateTime" readonly #fromDate>
      <span [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt1" class="calendar"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
      <owl-date-time #dt1></owl-date-time>

      <input #toDate [owlDateTime]="dt2" [(ngModel)]="dateTime" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt2" readonly
        (ngModelChange)="onChange($event,fromDate.value,toDate.value)">
      <span [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt2" class="calendar"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
      <owl-date-time #dt2></owl-date-time>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
  public dateTime: any;
  dt: any;
  dt1: any;
  dt2: any;


  onChange(data: any, fromDatePicker: any, toDatePicker: any) {
    console.log(fromDatePicker, toDatePicker);
    if (fromDatePicker !== '' && toDatePicker !== '') {
console.log(fromDatePicker,toDatePicker);
      }

    else {
      console.log('Either one of the date is empty');
    }
  }
```

**any solution please ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies within `[(ngModel)]="dateTime"` try to change both of them like: for FromDate take `[(ngModel)]="fromDate"` and for ToDate take `[(ngModel)]="toDate"` of course you need to define both in your component.ts

Basic example:

```
<span>From Date (UTC) *&nbsp;</span>    
<p-calendar class="date"
    (onSelect)="onChangeDate()"
    [(ngModel)]="model.start_date"
    [maxDate]="dateTime"
    [showIcon]="true"
    showButtonBar="true"
    [readonlyInput]="true"></p-calendar>

    <span>To Date (UTC) *&nbsp;</span>
    <p-calendar class="date"
    [(ngModel)]="model.end_date"
    showButtonBar="true"
    [showIcon]="true"
    [formControl]="form.controls['end_date']"
    (onSelect)="onChangeDate()"
    [readonlyInput]="true"></p-calendar>
```

Comment: Purvang Gor: Thank you so much for the help, it works now... god bless :)

Comment: Glad that I could help! :)